# How I can follow the redirections By Refresh meta tag With Python3

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-3.7, python-re

I know that requests module in python help to follow redirections, But if Target use Refresh Meta Tag
for Redirect user to another page requests module can't diagnose this attempt ...

For Example https://demo.tractmanager.com/ Redirect us to another page and requests module just can diagnose port of this page https://demo.tractmanager.com:443/

I want fix this problem with Regular Expressions Module (re) But I think that isn't good choice for solve it!

what's your suggestion and prefer?

For example I coded like that

```
    fopen2 = open("clean url.txt", "r")
    splurl = fopen2.read().split('\n')
    for i in splurl:
        getthis = requests.get(i)
        sop = BeautifulSoup(getthis.text, 'html.parser')
        if "http-equiv=\"refresh\"" in sop:
            print('yes')
        else:
            print(getthis.url)
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Use a context manager to avoid a memory leak: `with open("clean url.txt") as f:`. I don't understand what regex has to do with redirects. I don't know how `in` works relative to a BeautifulSoup object. If you're just checking a substring, you can use it on `getthis.text` directly.

Comment: I'd think that i can fetch last URL with replacing string and save addr in a variable

Comment: ggorlen Please give me a example code . thanks <3

Comment: I'd love to but I have no idea what you're trying to achieve here. What output/behavior do you expect from this code?

Comment: ggorlen in this case i want that output be https://demo.tractmanager.com/Contracts/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fcontracts link

Comment: The page content of the URL is `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://demo.tractmanager.com/contracts"/>` so I'm not sure how you'd get that link you want from that. Basically, after following redirects, you want to know the final page url?

Comment: Yes i want do this but in for loop